# Laravel - converting a collection to a simple array

Tags: php, laravel

so I have this code:

```
    $collectionOfProducts = \DB::table('products_specif')->whereIn('size',$arrayOfAttributes)->whereIn('color',$arrayOfAttributes)->whereIn('material',$arrayOfAttributes)->get('product_code');
    $product_codes = $collectionOfProducts->unique();
    dd($product_codes->toArray());
    $arrayOfProducts = \DB::table('products')->whereIn('product_code',$product_codes)->get();
    return view('pages.products', compact('arrayOfProducts','type'));
```

the dd() responds with:

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => {#1252 ▼
    +"product_code": "SocksCode"
  }
  4 => {#1257 ▶}
  9 => {#1262 ▶}
  13 => {#1266 ▶}
]
```

I would like to use the $product_codes in my **whereIn** statement, but I can't because of those numbers at the start(0,4,9,13).
How do I convert this collection/array to just a simple **"product_code" : "code"** array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pluck method to get array of `product_code`

```
$product_codes= \DB::table('products_specif')
->whereIn('size',$arrayOfAttributes)
->whereIn('color',$arrayOfAttributes)
->whereIn('material',$arrayOfAttributes)->pluck('product_code')->toArray();

$arrayOfProducts = \DB::table('products')->whereIn('product_code',$product_codes)->get();
```

Comment: select the answer please.. glad to help you :)\